# Why we use serializers instead of full clean to validate models or should we use them interchangeably?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-validation

I am working on a API server which uses Django Rest Framework. I have been using model's clean method to validate my models and calling full clean in views. It does not work properly for every situation. I sense there are some mistakes in my logic. I have never used any serializer and don't know should i use it or not while using full clean. So my question is how can I validate my models in a proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializers are not used just for model validation. You can also validate the payload of a POST request, convert your python dicts (or lists) to json and vice versa, etc.
Also, with write_only/read_only configuration, serializers give you an easy way, to determine which of the model fields are required for the client to provide in the payload and which of them will just be included in the response. Have a look in the documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/ to get an even better understanding.

Comment: I see your point. But actually my question was, why we need serializer validation while we have model validation.

Comment: Because:
1. it's one step before model validation
2. you can add custom validation fields that you don't need in model
3. it's out of the box functionality that comes with DRF and helps you program faster